# How to debug my rest webservices maven project using postman ?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jersey

I have my rest api java maven project. I am using jersey services.When I run my Main.java class the server starts. I have many methods for the creating endpoints to send responses for requests. I want to debug the methods when I send the request through Postman rest api client. I am running the application on localhost. How to do this ? Running my application in debug mode doesn't help. Any tutorials or blogs would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Provide IDE and Server Details, As of Now just restart server into debug mode

Comment: IDE - Eclipse        Server - localhost

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just needed to stop the server and then restart in debug mode.

Comment: @n9153 its my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem? Did you run it from IDE in debug mode?

Comment: I have kept breakpoints for the methods. But the debugger is not stopping . Means the dubug mode is not working. It directly executes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just needed to stop the server and then restart in debug mode.